# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS graphics problem, booting to  tty

Tags: nvidia, gui, gdm

Since I upgraded my computer to 12.04 from 11.04 nothing works anymore.

My Hardware:

- Intel® Core™2 Duo
- NVIDIA graphics card

First I had Problems running the my old user (I guessed it had something to do wie ID and GID), so I just saved everything and deleted that account.

But still everything was running unstable and I figured out it must be because I had Win Vista also running on this computer, so giving Ubuntu another chance I reinstalled EVERYTHING, including deleting all partitions so Ubuntu would be the only OS.

And still everything was running horrible, like the system was very slow, the screen was having little blackouts like (I think all relating to the Graphics card?). I thought it might be because lightdm is unstable so I uninstalled it and put gdm on (I already used falback-session because of it's more convenient look).

It was running ok after that (not fast though, still screen problems, etc) but suddenly it started booting into the terminal. I tried running `startx` and it seemed to load but then the system froze.

Now I'm running from the liveCD (which works totally fine!?).

I'm very desperate and I'd like to give Ubuntu a 5th (or something) chance but I won't work with a totally unstable system. Please help!

Comment: Check your disk for defects by entering the live cd and choosing, Check for Defects. did you create a Swap space also? If live session runs fine, there may be some issues with your hard drive(not sure, but I had the same slowness with my old hard drive which is almost dead)

Comment: I recommend you to give a *5th* chance. If Live CD is OK, the installation also should.

Comment: Just clarifying , what exactly is your Nvidia GUI. If it is Graphics Card , please post its Model number and other specifications too.

Comment: I don't know the Model because I can't find any manual for the PC and Ubuntu doesn't tell me what it is in the settings!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Do not worry.**

- Stay at your tty.
- Login and enter your password.
- Type to edit **rc-sysinit.conf** with **vim**:

  ```
   sudo vim /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf
  ```
- Find this string in **rc-sysinit.conf**:

  ```
   env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2
  ```
- If this value is different change it as shown above.
- ***Save the file***, Close **vim**
- Type in your tty:

  ```
   reboot
  ```

  Press Enter, and never worry :)